# C# Console Serial Port Read losing data

Tags: c#, arduino, bluetooth, serial-port

I tried to run serial communication using C# from Microsoft Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1. and I connecting with HC-06 Bluetooth Module which connected with an Arduino Nano Board.

The problem is when running it on my Laptop it seems to lose a lot of data, I'm not sure what causes this problem. However, when I running it on my Desktop it is seem everything working fine. By Desktop lose only 1 or 2 data in 200 samples per second, while on laptop loss around 50~70 samples. (I'm sure it does not cause by Arduino Part from my experiment over and over again on Desktop it receiving data around 200 samples per second as mention above).

Can it cause by my CPU?
*Laptop CPU: Core-I7-6700
*Desktop CPU: Core-i7-7700

(I add some codes to original codes writing a data to text file)
Here are C# console codes:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class PortChat
{
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static String myPath;
    public static void Main()
    {
        string name;
        string message;
        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

        myPath = Mypath();
        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
        _serialPort.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(_serialPort.BaudRate);
        _serialPort.Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort.Parity);
        _serialPort.DataBits = SetPortDataBits(_serialPort.DataBits);
        _serialPort.StopBits = SetPortStopBits(_serialPort.StopBits);
        _serialPort.Handshake = SetPortHandshake(_serialPort.Handshake);

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

        _serialPort.Open();
        _continue = true;
        readThread.Start();

        Console.Write("Name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

        while (_continue)
        {
            message = Console.ReadLine();

            if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
            {
                _continue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _serialPort.WriteLine(
                    String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
            }
        }

        readThread.Join();
        _serialPort.Close();
    }

    public static void Read()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {
                string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.ffffff");
                string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                string data = time + "," + message.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                WriteFile(Path, data);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }

    public static String Mypath()
    {
        string Path;
        Console.WriteLine("-> Logging Data <-");
        Console.Write("-> Input File Name: ");
        Path = Console.ReadLine();

        if(Path == "")
        {
            Path = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.ffffff");
        }

        return Path + ".txt";
    }

    static void WriteFile(String Path, String Data)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Data);
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(Data);
        }
    }

    // Display Port values and prompt user to enter a port.
    public static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
    {
        string portName;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
        portName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (portName == "" || !(portName.ToLower()).StartsWith("com"))
        {
            portName = defaultPortName;
        }
        return portName;
    }
    // Display BaudRate values and prompt user to enter a value.
    public static int SetPortBaudRate(int defaultPortBaudRate)
    {
        string baudRate;

        Console.Write("Baud Rate(default:{0}): ", defaultPortBaudRate);
        baudRate = Console.ReadLine();

        if (baudRate == "")
        {
            baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
        }

        return int.Parse(baudRate);
    }

    // Display PortParity values and prompt user to enter a value.
    public static Parity SetPortParity(Parity defaultPortParity)
    {
        string parity;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Parity options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Parity)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Enter Parity value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortParity.ToString(), true);
        parity = Console.ReadLine();

        if (parity == "")
        {
            parity = defaultPortParity.ToString();
        }

        return (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
    }
    // Display DataBits values and prompt user to enter a value.
    public static int SetPortDataBits(int defaultPortDataBits)
    {
        string dataBits;

        Console.Write("Enter DataBits value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortDataBits);
        dataBits = Console.ReadLine();

        if (dataBits == "")
        {
            dataBits = defaultPortDataBits.ToString();
        }

        return int.Parse(dataBits.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    // Display StopBits values and prompt user to enter a value.
    public static StopBits SetPortStopBits(StopBits defaultPortStopBits)
    {
        string stopBits;

        Console.WriteLine("Available StopBits options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StopBits)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Enter StopBits value (None is not supported and \n" +
         "raises an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. \n (Default: {0}):", defaultPortStopBits.ToString());
        stopBits = Console.ReadLine();

        if (stopBits == "" )
        {
            stopBits = defaultPortStopBits.ToString();
        }

        return (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopBits, true);
    }
    public static Handshake SetPortHandshake(Handshake defaultPortHandshake)
    {
        string handshake;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Handshake options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Handshake)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Enter Handshake value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortHandshake.ToString());
        handshake = Console.ReadLine();

        if (handshake == "")
        {
            handshake = defaultPortHandshake.ToString();
        }

        return (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake, true);
    }
}
```

and Here is Arduino codes:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial HC06(2, 3);

void setup() {
HC06.begin(115200);
Timer1.initialize(5000); // micro second
Timer1.attachInterrupt(printout);
Timer1.start();
}

void printout()
{
  HC06.println(data());
}

String data()
{
  int d1 = analogRead(A0);
  int d2 = analogRead(A1);
  String d = String(d1) +","+ String(d2);
  return d;  
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

Comment: Also, I think that was a bad example to use.  C# isn't like embedded, it supports multi threading and events.  Running a endless while loop reading the serial port isn't ideal.  The `SerialPort` class has a `DataReceived` event that you can subscribe to and anytime data comes over the line it fires.  See this example, its much cleaner and easier to read and use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: It sounds like you are emulating a serial port via bluetooth.  There could be a ton of reasons why it doesn't work because of this.  It seems that if the code is working well on one environment (your pc) but not well on another environment (your laptop) that the issue is bluetooth related.  Could be the bluetooth in your laptop isn't as good as the one in your PC.  Also depends on the emulation software you used to make it appear as a com port.  For reliability always use a RS-232 serial cable between both devices.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use lower bitrate, lets say 9600? It might be, that high speed is not working good with Arduino.

Comment: I did with 19200 it's doesn't work well even on my Desktop.